# Strings are immutable then how the replace() works?

Tags: java, string

I was trying to replace the first letter/char of a string by it's last one and last one by it's first one.
E.g. abcd => dbca.
Strings are immutable in Java then how can we explain the behavior of this program?
Please have a look at final output. str1 has no char 'a' but in final output it appears unexpectedly.. how? 
     //The argument of frontBack() is String "abcd".

```
 public static void frontBack(String str) {
   String first= ""+str.charAt(0);
   System.out.println("first char is "+first);
   String last = ""+str.charAt(str.length()-1);
   System.out.println("last char is "+last);
   String str1;
   str1 = str.replace(""+str.charAt(0),last);
   System.out.println("String str1 is => "+str1);
   String str2 ;
   str2 = str1.replace(""+str1.charAt(str1.length()-1),first);
   System.out.println("String str2 is derived from str1(dbcd) which has no 'a' but o/p is =>  "+str2);    
  }
 /* Have a look at output:
                        first char is a
                        last char is d
                        String str1 is => dbcd
                        String str2 is derived from str1 i.e. "dbcd" which has no 'a' in it but o/p is =>  abca*/
```

Comment: replace doesn't change str. It creates a new string which you assign to str1.

Comment: Just read the docs, it creates a new String, and the old one is garbage collected.  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(char,%20char)

Comment: Please have a look at final output. str1 has no char 'a' but in final output it appears unexpectedly.. how?

Comment: The down votes are hurried responses please read the edit brothers!

Comment: I don't down vote, but your real questions doesn't have anything to do with immutability or even how `replace` works which is confusing.

Comment: It does relates to replace() working because the final output is puzzling.

Comment: Variables are not `String` objects, they are **references** to `String` objects. You can change a variable to refer to another `String`, but you cannot change the content of a `String` object.

Comment: Re-opened as the question is not actually about String immutability as the OP already knows.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, you have to understand that variables in Java (of non-primitive types) are not objects themselves, they are **references** to objects. Class `String` is immutable, which means that once a `String` object has been created, there is no way to change the content of the object. However, you *can* make a `String` variable refer to a different `String` object.

Let's look what is happening line by line. We start with `str` referring to a `String` object with the content `"abcd"`.

```
String first= ""+str.charAt(0);
```

This makes the variable `first` refer to a new `String` object with the content `"a"`.

```
String last = ""+str.charAt(str.length()-1);
```

This makes the variable `last` refer to a new `String` object containing only the last character of the `String` object that `str` refers to. So, `last` refers to a `String` object with the content `"d"`.

```
String str1;
str1 = str.replace(""+str.charAt(0),last);
```

The `replace()` method takes two arguments: the substring you want to find, and the string to replace it with. Note that `replace()` does **not** change the original `String` object; it returns a new `String` object with all occurrences of the first argument replaced by the second argument. See the [API documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence-).

`""+str.charAt(0)` is `"a"` and `last` is `"d"`, so this line is equivalent to:

```
str1 = str.replace("a", "d");
```

After this line, `str` still refers to the original `String` with content `"abcd"` and `str1` refers to a new `String` with content `"dbcd"`.

```
String str2 ;
str2 = str1.replace(""+str1.charAt(str1.length()-1),first);
```

In this line, the first argument to `replace()` is: `""+str1.charAt(str1.length()-1)` which is `"d"` (the last letter of the `String` that `str1` refers to).

The second argument is `first` which is `"a"`.

So this line is equivalent to:

```
str2 = str1.replace("d", "a");
```

After this line, `str1` still refers to the `String` with content `"dbcd"`, and `str2` refers to a new `String` object where all the letters `d` have been replaced by `a`, so: `"abca"`.

Comment: Thank you! It made me introspect the way I read Javadoc. This is really apreciable. I will try to improve!

Answer (score 6):

> Strings are immutable in Java then how can we explain the behavior of this program?

```
str1 = str.replace(""+str.charAt(0),last);
```

This method takes a String which is immutable and creates a new String which is immutable.  Immutable doesn't mean the String cannot be created.

Note: if you want to manipulate some text you can use a StringBuilder which is mutable.  You can create this from a String and you can create a new String from it.  This is often, but not always used, sometimes a `char[]` is used directly for performance reasons.

> the new string which is created has no char 'a' but in final output it appears unexpectedly.

This is where using a your debugger would help.  You would see that

```
String first= ""+str.charAt(0); // first = "a"
```

and later when you do

```
str2 = str1.replace(""+str1.charAt(str1.length()-1),first);
```

this is the same as

```
str2 = str1.replace("d", "a");
```

so it should be no surprise that the `d`s are replaced by `a`s

> I am using replace() not replaceAll()

From the Javadoc for [String.replace(CharSequence, CharSequence)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence-)

> Replaces each substring of this string that matches the literal target sequence with the specified literal replacement sequence.

Comment: But the new string which is created has no char 'a' but in final output it appears unexpectedly. I am puzzled at that.

Comment: I am using replace() not replaceAll()

Comment: You don't have any answer for this m sure!

Comment: @Deepeshkumar no, because it is already answered by the Javadoc for this method. I can't think or anything to add.